How to use loadExternalTokens in microsoft-authentication-library-for-js
We use Entra External ID in our angular application with the azure msal angular library.
We would like to use our own login page instead of the redirect. I am able to retrieve a access_token via the native authentication api of entra and I'd like to put this token information into the msal client to use it. I found the loadExternalTokens method and I am using it like that:
const silentRequest: SilentRequest = {
    scopes: combinedScopes,
    authority: msalConfig.auth.authority,
    account: {
        authorityType: 'MSSTS',
        homeAccountId: 'xxxxxxx-8e4c-4053-a0bc-xxxxxx-b406-xxxx-aad8-xxxxxxx',
        environment: 'xxxxx.ciamlogin.com',
        tenantId: 'xxxxxxx-b406-xxxxx-aad8-0fb725da75d2',
        username: myUsername,
        localAccountId: 'xxxxxx-8e4c-xxxx-a0bc-f1e19cbec012',
    },
};
const loadTokenOptions: LoadTokenOptions = {
    extendedExpiresOn: 6599,
};

let authresult = this.msalService.instance.getTokenCache().loadExternalTokens(silentRequest, r, loadTokenOptions);
this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(authresult.account)

This is not working, when I try to access a secured ressource, msalService redirects to the login screen.
